# VBA search and match values in few different sheets

Tags: excel, search, match, vba

I managed to write a code to search,match and import certain values between Worksheets("Check Database") and Worksheets("Civil DB").

```
For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
        mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "C").Value, wsc.Columns("A"), 0)
```

Values not found will go to Worksheets("Search")

```
   If IsError(mtch) Then
            .Cells(rw, "E") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value & " " & .Cells(rw, 
   "C").Value
             wser.Cells(rw, "N") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value
             wser.Cells(rw, "O") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value
```

How can I add code with 
would search columns in Worksheets("Search") and also in second Sheet called Worksheets("Airliners")

```
    Dim rw As Long, mtch As Variant, wsc As Worksheet

    Set wsc = Worksheets("Civil DB")
    Set wser = Worksheets("Search")
    Set wsa = Worksheets("Airliners")

    With Worksheets("Check Database")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
            mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "C").Value, wsc.Columns("A"), 0)


          ????????????


            If IsError(mtch) Then
                .Cells(rw, "E") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value & " " & .Cells(rw, "C").Value
                 wser.Cells(rw, "N") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value
                 wser.Cells(rw, "O") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value

            Else
                .Cells(rw, "D") = wsc.Cells(mtch, "B").Value


            End If
        Next rw
```

Comment: Right now code looks for matching vales in Col A in wsc worksheet, I would like to it additionally search values of Col A in wsa worksheet; the rest of the copy conditions would remain the same.

Comment: So it would treat  wsc worksheet and wsa worksheet as one combined single worksheet... @YowE3K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to check (and use) the "Airliners" sheet if there is no match in the "Civil DB" sheet, I think you are after:

```
'...
For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "C").Value, wsc.Columns("A"), 0)
    If IsError(mtch) Then
        'No match found in Civil DB, try in Airliners
        mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "C").Value, wsa.Columns("A"), 0)
        If IsError(mtch) Then
            'No match in Airliners either, so treat as error
            .Cells(rw, "E") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value & " " & .Cells(rw, "C").Value
             wser.Cells(rw, "N") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value
             wser.Cells(rw, "O") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value

        Else
            'Match in Airliners, so store value
            .Cells(rw, "D") = wsa.Cells(mtch, "B").Value
        End If
    Else
        'Match in Civil DB, so store value
        .Cells(rw, "D") = wsc.Cells(mtch, "B").Value
    End If
Next rw
```